# Doctrine: using different entity fields for different connections \ entity managers

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two Doctrine connections (postgres and sqlite) and entity:

```php
class MyEntity
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="my_custom_type")
     */
    private $field_for_pg;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $field_1_for_sqlite;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     */
    private $field_2_for_sqlite;
}
```

I'd like to have two different tables:

- with "field_for_pg" column in postgres database
- with "field_1_for_sqlite" and "field_2_for_sqlite" columns in sqlite database

How it can be implemented?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use two entity managers one configured for Postgre and the other one for sqlite each one have an entity directory which he handles.

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        default_entity_manager:   default
        entity_managers:
            postgre:
                connection:       postgreconnection
                mappings:
                    AppBundle:
                        dir:      Path/To/EntityFolder1
            sqli:
                connection:       sqliconnection
                mappings:
                    AppBundle:
                        dir:      Path/To/EntityFolder2
```

This way your entities are separated and handled between those two connections when you need to persist one entity for sqli use the sqli entity manager etc..

[Using Doctrine 2 Entity with different databases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12220198/using-doctrine-2-entity-with-different-databases)

Answer (score 0):

Doctrine entities uses one table per Entity. (not counting relations with other entities).

So you should divide your entity in two entities.

Comment: Then how can I specify which entity should be used in connection?